Getting better answers by smaller working precision?
I have the following code
(*Intialization*)
m = 41 10^2;
s = 6;
t = -Log[2, 10^-(s + 2)];

delta = 455 10^-4;
epsqkd = 10^-(s);

binent[p_] := -p Log[2, p] - (1 - p) Log[2, (1 - p)];

r = 119 10^-2  binent[delta];

epspa[nu_, beta_, alpha_] := 
  1/2 Sqrt[
    2^(-(m - beta m) (1 - binent[delta + nu]) + r (m - beta m) + t + 
       alpha m)];

gammaFunc[n_, k_, merr_, m_] := 1/(merr + 1) + 1/(m - merr + 1);


epspe[nu_, beta_] := 
  Sqrt[Exp[-2 (m - Floor[beta m]) Floor[
       beta m]^2 nu^2/(m Floor[beta m] + m)]];


(*Minimization*)
ars = {alpha, beta, nu};
cons = {alpha m, (2^-t + 2 epspe[nu, beta] + 
      epspa[nu, beta, alpha ]) <= epsqkd, 10^-5 <= alpha <= 10^-1, 
   3 10^-1 < beta <= 1/2, 0 < nu < 1/2 - delta};
res = NMaximize[cons, vars, Method -> "RandomSearch", 
  WorkingPrecision -> 30]
(2^-t + 2 epspe[nu, beta] + epspa[nu, beta, alpha ]) /. res[[2]]
cons /. res[[2]]

(*

During evaluation of In[380]:= NMaximize::incst: NMaximize was unable to generate any initial points satisfying the inequality constraints {-(99/100000000)+1/2 Sqrt[2^(Times[<<2>>]+Times[<<3>>]+Times[<<2>>]+Times[<<2>>])]+2 Sqrt[E^(-2 Power[<<2>>] Plus[<<2>>] Power[<<2>>] Power[<<2>>])]<=0}. The initial region specified may not contain any feasible points. Changing the initial region or specifying explicit initial points may provide a better solution.

During evaluation of In[380]:= NMaximize::cvmit: Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100 iterations.

Out[382]= {8.87616650203640100247159877344, {alpha -> 
   0.00216491865903326853718819482279, 
  beta -> 0.409570151726320941243386641872, 
  nu -> 0.121603873191085731786387214015}}

Out[383]= 1.312324529583111104343553567*10^-6

Out[384]= {8.8761665020364010024715987734, False, True, True, True}*)

The output does'nt satisfy all the constraints, namely the constraint
(2^-t + 2 epspe[nu, beta] + epspa[nu, beta, alpha ]) <= epsqkd

with epsqkd=10^-6 in this particular case.  I dont really mind slight violations since the value is really small anyway. The program outputs the value 1.312324529583111104343553567*10^-6, but ideally i would want the difference to be as low as possible.
How can I get the function to satisfy the constraints? I tried increasing the working precision but that seems to get worse results. Why does that happen?

Why not to minimize (2^-t + 2 epspe[nu, beta] + epspa[nu, beta, alpha ])- epsqkd first?
